# how to change iframe html within a bootstrap 2 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

I have access to change a JS file that is on the same domain as the iframes src but not served within the iframe content itself. I presume i have to wait until the iframe has loaded to change html but everything i try seems to fail.

The modal is opened when a button with an ID of "body_btnrewardsmodal" is clicked.

Here is my failed attempt.

HTML :

```
<div id="ajax-rewards-modal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="h3RewardsTitle" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="h3RewardsTitle">donut</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="divgiveafew">
            <iframe>
               <!DOCTYPE html>
               <html class="phone desktop-device firefox">
               <head></head>
               <body class="PopupWindow" onload="window.focus();">
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="span02">
                   text
                 </div>
               </div>
             </body>
             </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).on('click', '#body_btnrewardsmodal', function() {
    $('#divgiveafew iframe').load(function(){
        if ($('#divgiveafew iframe').contents().find('body').children().length > 0) {
            console.log('loaded');
            $('this').contents().find('.span02').prepend('<div class="alert alert-info" class="padding:8px;"><p style="margin:0">Some text</p> <ul class="unstyled inline"><li>#courageous</li><li>#innovative</li><li>#passionate</li><li>#adaptable</li><li>#honest</li><li>#thinkbig</li></ul></div>');
        } else {
            console.log('not loaded');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @Zl3n i need to add some html to the div / class (.span02) found within the iframe nested in a modal. I could be coding this all wrong :(

Comment: What do I want now? Not sure what more I can say? I would like to change iframe html via JS but its not working (as above).

Comment: Please edit your post and tell me what is the code inside the iframe. It is unclear for me there

Comment: does that help? thanks

Comment: no the modal and iframe already exist and work fine. I want to use js to change the html within the iframe. The JS file is not used in the iframe src but the iframe src is on the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for your help and reformatting. Your solution works for my question.

Comment: Delight to have helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your HTML, you call already the modal. Then You have to add an event when the modal is `shown`. There, you build the `div` you want to insert into the iframe.

Finally, when you are in the modal, you search for the iframe, get its content et prepend the content you just built.

```
$(this).find('iframe').contents().prepend(alert);
```

HTML reworked :

```
<div id="ajax-rewards-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="h3RewardsTitle" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="h3RewardsTitle">donut</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="divgiveafew">
            <iframe src="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button to open the modal -->
<a href="#ajax-rewards-modal" role="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</a>
```

And the JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ajax-rewards-modal').on('shown', function () {

        var alert = $('<div>', {'class' : 'alert alert-info', 'css' : {'padding' : '8px'}});
        $('<p>', {'css' : {'margin' : 0}, 'text' : 'Some Text'}).appendTo(alert);
        var ul = $('<ul>', {'class' : 'unstyled inline'}).appendTo(alert);
        $('<li>', {'text' : '#courageous'}).appendTo(ul);
        $('<li>', {'text' : '#innovative'}).appendTo(ul);
        $('<li>', {'text' : '#passionate'}).appendTo(ul);
        $('<li>', {'text' : '#adaptable'}).appendTo(ul);
        $('<li>', {'text' : '#honest'}).appendTo(ul);
        $('<li>', {'text' : '#thinkbig'}).appendTo(ul);

        $(this).find('iframe').contents().prepend(alert);
    });
});
```